# Objects of transitive verbs

Tags: grammar

When a word can be considered as an object? For example the following sentence from a dictionary, is provided under the entry for the word “**compensate**” when it functions as an intransitive verb so logically it shouldn’t have an object:

“*Her intelligence more than compensates for her lack of experience*.”

But it looks to me that “**her lack of experience**” is the object. Am I right?

Comment: There is no direct or indirect object in your example, if that's what you mean, so "compensate" is intransitive in your example. The noun phrase "her lack of experience" is object of the preposition "for", but not object of the verb "compensates".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is whether you are talking about DIRECT or INDIRECT objects. A TRANSITIVE VERB is one that takes a DIRECT OBJECT.

To find it, you ask **who** or **what** after the verb. Compensates **who** or **what**?

Her intelligence does NOT compensate **her lack of experience**. It compensates **for** her lack of intelligence.

To use the verb transitively, you could write:

> Her intelligence more than compensates **her parents** for the cost of her education.

Here the direct object is the parents.

To find an INDIRECT OBJECT you generally ask FOR WHOM/WHAT or TO WHOM/WHAT.

The answer is **for her lack of experience**.

In this case the phrase is better described as a non-core complement - see Billj's comment below and the stackexchange link.

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/452705/how-to-tell-if-something-is-a-core-complement-or-a-non-core-complement
https://writingexplained.org/grammar-dictionary/indirect-object
https://www.grammarly.com/blog/transitive-and-intransitive-verbs/
https://www.lexico.com/grammar/transitive-and-intransitive-verbs

Comment: I wouldn't say that "for her lack of experience" is indirect object. PPs are non-core complements, whereas core complements have the form of NPs.

Comment: Will adjust accordingly Bill. No-one had invented non-core complements in my day.

Comment: I know just what you mean! I was convinced by the following argument: In, for example, "I sent a copy to Sue", "Sue" is clearly the recipient, and many people would say that "Sue" (or "to Sue") is indirect object. But in the passive equivalent "Sue was sent a copy", again "Sue" is the recipient, but no one would want to say that "Sue" is indirect object here as she is clearly the subject.